# Get www/web content using HTTP request in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Could some one tell me how can I get www content in Pascal Code in Inno Setup Script?

Regards,
Tomasz

Answer (score 4):

Use [`WinHttpRequest` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/winhttprequest):

```pascal
var
  WinHttpReq: Variant;
begin
  WinHttpReq := CreateOleObject('WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1');
  WinHttpReq.Open('GET', 'https://www.example.com/', False);
  WinHttpReq.Send('');
  if WinHttpReq.Status <> 200 then
  begin
    Log('HTTP Error: ' + IntToStr(WinHttpReq.Status) + ' ' +
        WinHttpReq.StatusText);
  end
    else
  begin
    Log('HTTP Response: ' + WinHttpReq.ResponseText);
  end;
end;
```