# "A certificate is required to complete client authentication" Error during file download using innosetup download plugin

Tags: ssl, inno-setup, tls1.2, inno-download-plugin

While downloaidng setup files from server using the InnoSetup Download plugin it throws following error:

"A certificate is required to complete client authentication"

[image]

My Server where file is hosted supports the TLS1.0,1.1,1.2 protocols.
if i try the same url from browser , it works fine.
Please let me know the issue.

Code :

`idpaddfile(url,  ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Setup.exe'));`

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl : `https://www.idrive.com/downloads/IDriveSetup.exe`

Comment: Is that your server?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl : Yes.that is our production server where we upload the files for users to download our setup.

Comment: So try to find out why the server requests client certificate for incoming request from your installer.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl : when i try to download the file using c#.NET code it downloads successfully! can you please suggest where i have to look into.

Comment: I do not know. But your server is not compatible with [`WinHttpRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/winhttprequest) (used internally by IDP). Even a simple code like this does not work with your server: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42805224/850848. When I inspect the traffic between `WinHttpRequest` and your server using Wireshark, it's clear that the server requires the client certificate.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl : Okay, Thank you , is there any way to bypass the client certificate?

Comment: How bypass? The server requires it. The client cannot *"bypass"* the request.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl : Okay, can you suggest me any better solution now, can i expect any future updates where IDP will work with different method (other than WinHttpRequest) or can you suggest how i can set client certificate usinng innosetup?

Comment: No. IDP will hardly ever be reimplemented. + You cannot set client certificate and I doubt it would help, as I do not really think the server needs it, it just ask for it due to some bug/misconfiguration.

Comment: @Martin Prinkryl : Thank you for your suggestion, I will check the server if it is possible to reconfigure.Thank you 

Comment: @Sudhakar Tillapudi: Did you get a solution?